# Accessibilitywise, how long should submit buttons in forms be?

Tags: css, accessibility

Accessibilitywise, how long should submit buttons in forms be?

Is there a worldly accessibility standard for minimal height (as with `min-height` or font-size+padding CSS directives) for submit buttons in forms?

I ran the following search query in Gooogle:

> min-height submit button accessibility

No article I found included details about such a standard (not in the context of CSS min-height such as a pixel size, at least).

Comment: Some nice data in this Codidact post if someone wants to take a read: https://software.codidact.com/posts/281090

Answer (score 3):

There is one criterion in the current version (2.1) of the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) that provides some guidance to your question:

[Success Criterion 2.5.5: Target Size](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size.html) (Level AAA):

> The size of the target for pointer inputs is at least 44 by 44 CSS pixels except when...

Note that this is a AAA level criterion and many institutions use Level AA as their standard and might consider Level AAA as going above and beyond.

However, there is a proposed 2.2 version (still in draft) there is a new criterion that may be helpful to consider:

[Success Criterion 2.5.8: Target Size (Minimum)](https://w3c.github.io/wcag/understanding/target-size-minimum.html) (Level AA):

> The size of the target for pointer inputs is at least 24 by 24 CSS pixels, except where...

Note the exceptions in both articles as well as the additional context, but 24 by 24 CSS Pixels is probably a good baseline for a button not covered by any of the exceptions.